# Move Files from a Directory to Another Based on a Condition

Tags: python, if-statement, directory, subdirectory, pythonpath

I have a main directory that contains multiple folders. I wanna loop through these sub folders, check for each sub folder if it contains more than (e.g. 10 files) keep the 10 files and move the rest to a new directory, otherwise delete the subfolder.

This is how my directory looks like:

[image]

Each sub directory contains around 100 files, I wanna loop through these sub directories, do a check first, keep 10 files, and move the rest to a new directory.

I would presume that this can be done with the help of `pathlib` or `os` but I need a help in writing the script.

I think the code will be something like the following:

```
for directory in os.listdir('path'):
    for file in os.listdir(os.path.join('path', directory)):
        if(....){
          # keep 10 files and move the rest to a new directory
        } else {
          # delete the subdir
        }
```

Comment: Hi Mohammed, I've answered your question. Please take a look at it.

Comment: Hello Mohammad, have you seen my answer?

Comment: Sorry for being late Behadad, I was not able to check until now. Sounds awesome, I ll give it a try within few hours and let you know.

Comment: No problem brother :) I look forward to your response 

Comment: Works like a charm. Sincere THANKS :)

Comment: You're very welcome 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use `shutil` library for `moving` and `removing` files and directories, below is an example for `moving` a file from a path to another path:

```py
import shutil

original = r'original_path_where_the_file_is_currently_stored\file_name.file_extension'
target = r'target_path_where_the_file_will_be_moved\file_name.file_extension'

shutil.move(original,target)
```

And below is an example for removing a directory including all it's content:

```py
import shutil
dirPath = '/path_to_the_dir/name_of_dir/'
shutil.rmtree(dirPath)
```

We use the two snippets above to create the final code:

```py
import shutil
import os
new_dir_path = "path_to_the_new_dir/new_dir_name"
for directory in os.listdir('path'):
    for index, file in enumerate(file_list := os.listdir(path_dir := os.path.join('path', directory))):
        if(len(file_list) >= 10):
          # keep 10 files and move the rest to a new directory
            if(index > 9):
             shutil.move(os.path.join(path_dir,file),os.path.join(new_dir_path,file))
        else:
          # delete the subdir
          shutil.rmtree(path_dir)
```